# Cordova device plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a simple Phonegap Build application where I am trying to use the device plugin.  I have installed the plugin via command line and have confirmed that it is installed.

I have the following js inside onDeviceReady:

`alert(device.platform);` and `alert(device.model);`

I get white screen with no alerts.

Chrome dev tools remote inspect console says:
Uncaught ReferenceError: platform is not defined

The plugin is not being recognized.

Comment: Can we get a snippet of the code? is device defined (`console.log(device)`)?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also facing exactly the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this cordova pluign using this commend :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

[read More](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device)

```
Try this
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //add event listener
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() { 
       console.log(device); // device object 
       console.log(device.name); // Gives the name of device.
       console.log(device.uuid ); // Gives the UUID.
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> . Thank you, after importing cordova.js the problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    
    //add event listener
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    
    //device.name -> Gives the name of device.
    //device.cordova -> Gives current version of cordova running on device.
    //device.platrof -> Gives the name of platform.
    //device.uuid -> Gives the UUID.
    //device.version -> Gives the Android Version.

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var vInfo =  'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '\n' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '\n' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '\n' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '\n' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version;
       alert(vInfo);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phonegap build you don't have to install the plugins with the CLI, you have to add it in the config.xml file that you upload to phonegap build

Add this line:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device"/>
```

And don't use it before the `deviceready` event is fired.

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can solve this issue by using this  [cordova device plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device).Its an updated as well as live plugin with properties including model,platform,uuid,version,manufacturer,serial number etc...

you can add this plugin to your project via cli using the command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

if you have added any previous device plugins, please remove that prior to adding this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped with this same problem for awhile.  First I built to iOS and everything was working great, then I went to add the Android platform to make the app for Android and began getting the error.

Re-adding the plugin to my project after creating the Android platform fixed the error for me.  I'm sure there have to be others who have had the same issue, so I wanted to share.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

Answer (score 0):

If this is Angular/Ionic, you need to do two things:

1. `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx'` <- this is how the import should look like
2. Do the same import on the module that contains the components you gonna use the Device class, and add the cass to that module's provider.